# Is there a switch that will connect directly to my modem and allow my router to serve only as a WiFi connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, modem, switch

**Details**

*Devices*

- Internets -50Mbps Cable Internet
- Modem -  Motorola Surfboard Extreme
- Router - Netgear WNDR3700v3
- Switch - D-Link DGS-1008G
- Wired Ethernet Cable - Cat6_24Awg_
- Device Configuration - Modem\Router\Switch

**Internet Usage**

*Wired Demand*

- XBOX 360
- 1 Gaming PC
- 2 PC - HD video

*WiFi Demand*

3 android + 1 Laptop for browsing and group video chat simultaneously

**Specifics**

I am experiencing problems with network speeds and reliability on both wired and wireless connections. On many occasions I experience WiFi Speeds that vary between the 15mbps to 0.50 mbs (or less) and ping ranging from 15ms to 500ms. These results are from when I notice problems with internet lag and run speedtest.net to get details of problems.  I have a stretched out floor-plan and old building materials drastically affecting my cellphone signal strength as well).

After Reading the "Known Issues" Section on the webpage below

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNDR3700#Known_Issues

I bought the switch and Cat6 cable to increase speed and relieve stress on router in an attempt to fix the symptoms. I thought I'd use the router in a Modem\Switch\Router configuration. I thought I'd only have to use the router for mobile WiFi connections like android or Laptops when necessary (hopefully eliminating the problem caused by the router when subjected to all those demanding Ethernet connections)

When I started unboxing the switch, I noticed the manual of this DGS-1008G shows it being connected in the Modem\Router\Switch order and not in the Modem\Switch\Router configuration I was aiming for. I have not been able to find a solid plan to remedy my specific problem without buying another expensive router.

I would like to get the speeds I am paying for without buying another router. (My WiFi Adapters would also need to be updated if new router is required, meaning more $$$). I can always sell the switch and get a better one that will bypass the router because my most demanding internet connections are Wired.

**Questions**

1. Can I accomplish a Modem\Switch\Router configuration with current switch?
2. Is there a different way to get the wired speed I need while providing WiFi only when necessary?

Comment: Are those wifi devices in line of sight with router? Are you using dd-wrt firmware? I would say that using shielded cables isn't a good idea if those are not properly grounded on both ends. How far those devices are (modem -> switch -> router)?

Comment: "Are those wifi devices in line of sight with router?" >No. Floor Plan has weird layout with a winding hallway. "Are you using dd-wrt firmware?" >Yes, but I had the same issue with fully updated Netgear Firmware. "I would say that using shielded cables isn't a good idea if those are not properly grounded on both ends." >Good point. Never considered that. How do I check to see if properly grounded? "How far those devices are (modem -> switch -> router)?" >Modem - 1ft - switch - 5ft - router.

Comment: PS - I also have a line connected to switch 100ft to another part of the house plugged directly into PC Ethernet port. Should I have a different configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Connect only the Switch to the Modem.
2. Connect the WiFi router to one of the  ports on that switch (a port similar to the one you would connect other hardwired devies on)

Config:

1. The wifi router can remain a DHCP for the WiFi LAN. For the wifi router to be able to talk to the switch the WiFi router will have to be configued with a static IP of its own(just like any other device thats connected to the switch).
2. Since you have all your other hardware already configured to use the switch (hardwired) and the Wireless Devices configured to use the same router, "NO" config changes will be required on either the hardwired devices or the Wifi devices.
3. Apart from the Static IP update stated above, no config changes should be done on the Router.
4. If you have any hard wired connections into the router and you are re-connecting them now to the switch, make sure those devices are re-configured with static IPs, so as to be able to talk to the switch.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you configure with the switch between the modem and router, you will need to

   a) use fixed, manual IP addressing for every device on your network

   b) reconfigure the Netgear so serve only as a Wireless Access Point, disabling DHCP and routing services. http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19852 has a step by step procedure for a dual-router setup if you are still using the original Netgear firmware, and you can use those instructions for your modem - > switch -> router-as-WAP configuration.
2. As to the erratic speed and throughput, when I did Network support on the Xbox360 team, the WNDR3700 was viewed as the 'go-to' device; when folks asked, it was one of the few we would note worked well with multiple Xbox360 consoles. I smell something wrong with your particular device, and recommend reflashing the router's OS (whether using DD-WRT or the original Netgear firmware) after a back-panel reset.
3. And, should your Netgear be located at one end of the house, I would suggest reshaping the WiFi signal into a beam with http://www.freeantennas.com/projects/template2/index.html  to increase signal strength where you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am glad to see that it is possible. I will get back to you as soon as I get a chance to work on this again. They are all very good suggestions, but I am a slow learner who happens to live in a low population, high unemployment area and have medical debt. For now I just have the router plugged into the modem and the 100ft cat6 coboc cable from the router. The switch is unplugged until I have the time to work on it.